# How to handle the loop in the uithread,in android?like ios "NSRunLoop" and C#5.0 asyn...wait

Tags: android, ios, multithreading

The ios can start a async method,and wait in the main thread with a nsrunloop

```
while(!iterationDone) { 
    [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]]; 
    //do other stufff 
  }
```

with this,the uithread can keep alive,and i can keep the sequence of invoke many async method. it just easily  invode like  sync method.

```
 public int asyncmethod1{
        new Handler.post(new Runnable() { 
          @Override 
          public void run() { 
               // Do something on the UI-Thread 
             } 
          }); 
        //while(handler is end)
        //return the result 
 }
 public void main(){
    int i= asyncmethod1();
    i+=asyncmethod2();
 }
```

but this method must be cause the uithread not responsed.

Answer (score 0):

In Android there are two many concepts to handle async tasks and do something on the UI-Thread.

1) The Handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

```
new Handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something on the UI-Thread
    }
});
```

2) The AsyncTask

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform  background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate hreads and/or handlers. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

A usage example for the AsyncTask is at the developer site of Android.

Comment: thank for the answer,but I means to use It as synchronize method to return a value which can aso keep uithrad alive.just like                                                                 new Handler.post(new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        // Do something on the UI-Thread 
    } 
});       while(!iterationDone) {//wait the thread above}    return value;